# Win10 / Sierra / Bootcamp - cannot see OS X partition, no CoreStorage, no FileVault

Tags: bootcamp, windows, macos

After installing one of the major Windows 10 updates a while ago, I lost the functionality of seeing the HFS+ partition under Windows 10. After reading up on this issue and finding a number of threads where users experience the same issue, I am still unable to find a solution that allows me to regain this function natively without the use of third-party apps such as MacDrive or Paragon.

Funny thing is that I am not running on CoreStorage and have FileVault disabled, hence cannot tell why this is not working as it supposedly is provided as part of the latest Bootcamp drivers.

Any ideas?

Terminal Disk Info:

```
MacBook-Air:~ User$ sudo diskutil list
Password:
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:         Microsoft Reserved                         16.8 MB    disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            116.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS                         8.0 GB     disk0s4
   5:                        EFI NO NAME                 237.0 MB   disk0s5
   6:       Microsoft Basic Data Windows 10              124.0 GB   disk0s6
   7:       Microsoft Basic Data Webserver               1.1 GB     disk0s7

MacBook-Air:~ User$ sudo diskutil cs list
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
MacBook-Air:~ User$ sudo gpt -r -vvv show -l /dev/disk0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: mediasize=251000193024; sectorsize=512; blocks=490234752
gpt show: /dev/disk0: PMBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=E3C9E316-0B5C-4DB8-817D-F92DF00215AE, start=2048, size=32768
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC, start=409640, size=227248312
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC, start=227657952, size=1269536
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC, start=228927488, size=15624192
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B, start=244553728, size=462848
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7, start=245938176, size=242198528
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7, start=488136704, size=2095104
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Sec GPT at sector 490234751
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34       2014         
       2048      32768      1  GPT part - "Microsoft reserved partition"
      34816     374824         
     409640  227248312      2  GPT part - ""
  227657952    1269536      3  GPT part - ""
  228927488   15624192      4  GPT part - "OSXRESERVED"
  244551680       2048         
  244553728     462848      5  GPT part - "EFI system partition"
  245016576     921600         
  245938176  242198528      6  GPT part - "Basic data partition"
  488136704    2095104      7  GPT part - "Basic data partition"
  490231808       2911         
  490234719         32         Sec GPT table
  490234751          1         Sec GPT header
MacBook-Air:~ User$ sudo fdisk /dev/disk0
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 30515/255/63 [490234752 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -  490234751] <Unknown ID>
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

Comment: its a Macbook Air 13in early 2015. The additional Disks are (as far as I know, they just popped up after the Sierra and Win10 update) are 1. Win10 / 2. MAC / 3. Win10 Recovery / 4. Mac Recovery. I wouldnt worry too much about the smaller partitions, they seem legit to me.

Comment: No, some of them don't seem legit to me: The default OS X & BootCamp layout is: 1. 200 MiB EFI 2. OS X main 3. 650 MB OS X Recovery (4. 2nd EFI) 5. Windows main 6. additional Windows partitions. The remains of the 200 MiB default EFI are still there: parts of the 2014 blocks gap and the 374824 blocks gap.

Comment: I see that this is not the accurate partitioning, but I dont understand why this would affect the way the bootcamp drivers read the HFS volume? Can I delete the unnecessary EFI partitions via DiskUtil on MAC? Which Disk# should I delete?

Comment: The disk0s5 EFI may be necessary: it depends on how you installed Windows 10 (either the MBR or the GPT method) and what the Win10 update has modified. In my opinion your problem is related with the missing disk0s1 OS X EFI (overwritten/replaced by the disk0s1 MS reserved partition)

Comment: so easiest solution would be to wipe the whole HDD via OSX Recovery and then go again with Bootcamp and Win10? Thats a little overkill, isnt it?

Comment: I would recommend a proper reinstall to not further degrade your partition scheme (e.g. after the next Win10 update), yes. It depends on the effort, of course. It is possible to replace your current disk0s1 by a proper OS X EFI. But this may break Win10 booting - I simply don't know how you installed Windows and what happened afterwards. So it would require a backup of at least the two Win partitions or better a dd of the whole disk.

Answer (score 1):

As I do not want to wipe the whole HDD and backup two system partitions, I instead installed Paragon HFS+ for Win10 which ultimately fixed the issue. Give that Paragon merely installs drivers for HFS+ interaction, I tend to believe that the bootcamp drivers must have been affected during one of the Windows Updates, hence suggest others with the same problem to first re-install the bootcamp drivers before turning to Paragon.

The most up to date bootcamp drivers for your apple notebook can be found on the Windows Recovery Drive in the WinPEDriver Folder, you maybe have to assign a drive letter to the partition first (right-click "This PC" > Manage > Disk Management > right-click WINRECOVERY and click "assign Drive Letter").

Hope that helps

[image]